# passing variables to function with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, onclick

I'm new to javascript although I do use PHP.

I'm having issues passing variables using javascript/jquery on an onclick event on a href.

I'm pulling json data from a remote URL and there are 3 parameters that need to go with each request.

Date, price and currency.

I have a function to build the URL that looks like this:

```
function getIndexData(date, price, currency){
    ajaxURL = "/data/"+date+"/"+price+"/"+currency+"";
}
```

This works well and builds the URL I need.

However, I have a jquery datepicker on the page to change the date to whatever I want which looks like:

```
$(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    getIndexData(date, price, currency )
                }
            }
        );
    });
```

Even if price and currency have previously been set they are now 'undefined'.

I have the same issue with the onclick events - if I try to send the price or the currency using (for example):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getIndexData('date','price','currency')">NET</a></span>
```

price and currency are undefined.

Is there a way I can send only one of the variables to my function whilst retaining the already existent values?

Apologies for what must be a really basic question.  I'm just new to this and I've obviously misunderstood something along the way.

Comment: If you could create a fiddle or snippet, it would definitely help.

Comment: `onSelect: function (date) {`  need to be `onSelect: function (date, price, currency) {`. that means you have to pass all three variable to your onselect callback

Comment: ^ One wonders why the datepicker `onSelect` method would have those three arguments, when it should have only two, the date and the instance?

Comment: So where are you setting the price, currency etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is the updated answer. As you can see, if variables are declared in the global scope of the code, the date picker function will have access to it. I think it previously did not work because the html was wrong. I deleted all of the html and included only the date picker and if you test it in the browser, you will see that in the console the price, currency variables are available inside date picker onSelect function and you can also execute the function getIndexData inside it. I've assigned the function to a variable that way you can use the variable getIndexData if you want to use the function.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="col-sm-5 index-grid">
  <span class="grid-label">Price</span>
  <span class="btn btn-grid"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getIndexData(indexDate, indexCurrency ,indexPrice);">CLOSE</a></span>
   <span class="btn btn-grid"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getIndexData(indexDate, indexCurrency ,indexPrice);">RETURN</a></span>
  <span class="btn btn-grid"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getIndexData(indexDate, indexCurrency ,indexPrice);">NET</a></span>
</div>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
  </body>
  </html>
<script>

var ajaxURL;
var indexDate = "2017-08-20"
var indexPrice = "closeprice";
var indexCurrency = "EUR";


var getIndexData = function (indexDate, indexCurrency, indexPrice) {
  ajaxURL = "/data/" + indexDate + "/" + indexPrice + "/" + indexCurrency + "";
  alert(ajaxURL);

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
      onSelect: function(date) {
      console.log(date);
      console.log(indexPrice);
      console.log(indexCurrency);
      console.log(getIndexData);

      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: neither of these appear to work but I guess that's likely just because I'm so confused about this.  I just want to be able to pass single parameters to a function whilst retaining values that already exist for the other ones but this has me so confused.

Comment: If you can show me more code or a js fiddle I will be glad to look more into it

Comment: thanks - I'll try to put the code here and see if it helps - it's excerpts of the code.  Can't past the code here as it is too long.

Comment: Well it would be good at least to see where the price and currency variables come from and where they are set

Comment: I've put some html and javascript in a fiddle but obviously it is not working.
https://jsfiddle.net/uy9Lf0jc/

Comment: I've tested and that works - so all good there.  Thank you for your help.  So what if I then want to pass either the IndexCurrency or the Indexprice via an onclick on a button/link?

This was definitely a huge sticking point before: how to choose one and still retain the others?

Comment: I've updated the answer again and the onclick function now works.

Answer (score 0):

If you declared price and currency outside of :

```
$(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    getIndexData(date, price, currency )
                }
            }
        );
    });
```

Then what you need to do is use the "this" keyword to access the values of price and currency. Just like the example below.
You may also want to check this link for more insight : https://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/

```
$(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    getIndexData(date, this.price, this.currency )
                }
            }
        );
    });
```